# why input value cannot be access inside function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why the variable is empty when accessing inside a function? Please see my code below

```js
var age = document.getElementById('ageValue').value

function getAge() {
    document.getElementById('age').innerHTML = 'Your age is: ' + age
}
```

```html
<div id="age"></div>

<input type="text" id="ageValue">

<button type="button" onclick="getAge()">Show Age</button>
```

Comment: You only read the value once before there is anything there.

Comment: @VLAZ what should be the solution for this?

Comment: Read the value every time. Not just once.

Answer (score 2):

Put the reading the age part inside the function.

```js
function getAge() {
    var age = document.getElementById('ageValue').value;
    document.getElementById('age').innerHTML = 'Your age is: ' + age
}
```

```html
<div id="age"></div>

<input type="text" id="ageValue">

<button type="button" onclick="getAge()">Show Age</button>
```